# angular: calculating age base on date of birth

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to calculate age based on the date of birth but for some reason it is working properly.

Here is angular code:

Data is coming from http request.

```
   $scope.dob = data.dob;
```

sample data - 02-01-1990. (dd-mm-yyyy).

```
$scope.calculateAge = function calculateAge(birthday) { // birthday is a date
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

This is how i am using.

```
{{ calculateAge(dob) }}
```

Please advise.

Comment: var d = new Date("02-01-1990") does not parse. Are you past this part? It's not clear to me from the question.

Comment: what does "it is failing" mean?  are you getting an error? are you getting an incorrect result? is something else happening?  Your question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: It's failing or not producing desired results because your birthDate is in "dd-mm-yyyy" format and Date() class doesn't understand this format. So the date difference wouldn't output expected results. i.e.  birthday.getTime() evaluates the input date as  01 Feb 1990(mm-dd-yyyy) format. Try using moment.js to convert dates in a common base form.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ageDifMs` is milliseconds of the difference, so you can calculate the difference pretty easily based on number of milliseconds in a year:

```
return Math.floor(ageDifMs / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);
```

Additionally if you are using `02-01-1990` format, you can't give this to `new Date`. Instead, I recommend using the [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library for JavaScript which can also easily create dates from provided formats and calculate the difference between two dates using any metric (including years).

Answer (score 0):

Your function to calculate the age seems to be working correctly.

You can replace the $timeout by your $http request and do something similar to this:

```js
angular.module('webapp', [])
        .controller('dummyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.age = 'NOT DEFINED';
          
            // This simulates the synchronicity of the http request
            $timeout(function () {
              $scope.calculateAge(new Date(2000, 10, 10));
            }, 1000);
          
            $scope.calculateAge = function calculateAge(birthday) {
                console.log(birthday); 
                // birthday is a date
                var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
                var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
                $scope.age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
            };
        }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="webapp">
        <head>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="webapp">
            <div ng-controller="dummyCtrl">
                <span ng-bind="age"></span>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```